Codemagic can't access GitHub repo with permission denied error
I got a permission error even when I got my token and put it on the environment variables in Codemagic
my error
remote: Permission to Icarus-conf/fc_lang.git denied to Icarus-conf.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Icarus-conf/fc_lang/': The requested URL returned error: 403

my codemagic.yaml file
workflows:
  build_and_deploy:
    name: Build and Deploy to GitHub Pages
    environment:
      flutter: stable
      groups:
        - repo_credentials
    scripts:
      - name: Install dependencies
        script: |
          flutter pub get

      - name: Build web
        script: |
          flutter build web --release --no-tree-shake-icons

      - name: Verify build output
        script: |
          if [ ! -d "build/web" ]; then
            echo "Build directory does not exist. Aborting."
            exit 1
          fi
          ls -la build/web

      - name: Configure Git
        script: |
          git config --global user.name "$GIT_USER_NAME"
          git config --global user.email "$GIT_USER_EMAIL"
          git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
          echo "https://$APP_PASSWORD:@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials

      - name: Checkout web branch
        script: |
          git fetch --all
          if git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/web-branch; then
            git checkout web-branch
          else
            git checkout -b web-branch
          fi

      - name: Copy built files to web branch
        script: |
          rm -rf *  # Clear the web branch directory
          cp -R build/web/* .
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update web branch with latest changes from main" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push origin web-branch

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        script: |
          git checkout -B gh-pages
          git add .
          git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push --force origin gh-pages

artifacts:
  - build/web

I got a permission error even when I got my token and put it on the environment variables in Codemagic.

from the yaml file you shared, next line doesn't look correct to me
echo "https://$APP_PASSWORD:@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials

Namely it should be something like $GIT_USER_NAME:$APP_PASSWORD but you have password as a username.
Also you can consider using GitHub CLI tools for authentication
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

remote: Permission to Icarus-conf/fc_lang.git denied to Icarus-conf.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Icarus-conf/fc_lang/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Build failed :|
Step 8 script Copy built files to web branch exited with status code 128, stil the same error

you really should double check what credentials do you use

one way to debug this problem is to SSH to builder machine and check .git-credentials content and try to execute the same commands from terminal. See more information about remote access here https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/

the thing is i'm not good with this, this is my first time to do that, i can't figure it out how to give it a permission, don't know the right code to write, please help if  u can
